# BigQuery filter if column has a certain value, then pivot results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to filter on `EnterpriseNumber` that have a row `ContactType` of TEL.
Then I want to pivot the table so the values of `TEL` and `EMAIL` show in a column

```
| EnterpriseNumber | Denomination     | ContactType | Value                |
|------------------|------------------|-------------|----------------------|
| 900              | Jonas            | null        | null                 |
| 900              | Jonas            | null        | null                 |
| 750              | Marie            | TEL         | 111000               |
| 750              | Marie            | EMAIL       | 750@domain.com       |
| 500              | Jimmy            | TEL         | 333000               |
| 400              | Johanna          | EMAIL       | 500@domain.com       |
```

The result I want:

```
| EnterpriseNumber | Denomination     | TEL    | EMAIL                |
|------------------|------------------|--------|----------------------|
| 750              | Marie            | 111000 | 750@domain.com       |    
| 500              | Jimmy            | 333000 | null                 |
```

Its really hard for me to do it, I know I probably need to use the PIVOT function, but I couldn't make it work. Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select enterprisenumber, denomination,
       max(case when contacttype = 'TEL' then value end) as telephone,
       max(case when contacttype = 'EMAIL' then value end) as email
from t
group by 1, 2;
```

I'm not sure why you are filtering out the first person.  You can use a `where` or `having` clause for that.  Perhaps:

```
where contacttype is not null
```

Comment: Changed some data to make its simpler

Comment: what does the group by 1, 2 mean?

Comment: it is equivalent to `GROUP BY enterprisenumber, denomination` meaning by first and second column